# How to calculate cumulative costs using formulas?

Tags: ms-project

Used by:
  - MS Project 2016 Pro. Desktop

I am in the Gantt Chart view.

How to calculate `cumulative costs` using formulas?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Formulas are task-level calculations and cannot get/use information from other tasks.

You *could* do this with VBA, however since the order of tasks is mutable (e.g. tasks can be moved, deleted, inserted, etc) it doesn't make much sense to have a field showing cumulative values. You would need to recalculate the field frequently to ensure it is correct.

Comment: **1.** Can I somehow get the `cumulative costs` in a different view?
**2.** On the right side of the `Task Usage` view, I see `cumulative costs`, if I understand you correctly, then on the left side of the view, I can not configure `cumulative costs`?
**3.** How to get `cumulative costs` using VBA (C #)?

Comment: 1 & 2) `Cumulative Cost` as shown in the `Task Usage` view is cumulative across *time*; it is a [time-phased field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cumulative-cost-fields-287d06ef-92af-42eb-87ba-444e3b4f327b) and thus is visible only in time-phase views (`Task Usage` and `Resource Usage`). This is completely different than a running sum of the costs of tasks under a summary task.

Comment: 3) `Cumulative Cost` has no meaning at the task level--it would be the same as the `Cost` field itself. It only has meaning by time-periods--for example, if you wanted to see the cost totals by week or month. And for that, just look at the `Task Usage` view and set the zoom to show the time periods you want.